# Enrollment iOS agent at WSO2: authentification failed

Tags: ios, authentication, wso2

I have next problem with WSO2EMM:

1. I get Apple certificate and install it on server.
2. Generated self-signed ipa and install it on server.
3. Add iOS Features on Carbon Console.
4. Registered and invite user.
5. On iPhone I load and install certificate(it's verified), load and install MDM agent.
6. But when I want to register agent, I see the Domain field is required, but in invitation email it is empty.

So, when I type login and pass without domain, I get "Unexpected error".
I try set domain as my server domain name and enable/disable Multitenancy at Home    > Configure     > Multitenancy  > View Tenants in Carbon Console, but poorly.
However, for Android registration and all functions work fine.
And that I see in log during registration iOS agent:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-11 23:32:03,455] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  Trying to select a resource class, request path : //oauth2/token
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-11 23:32:03,455] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  No resource class match for org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint, request path : //oauth2/token
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-11 23:32:03,456] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  No resource class match for org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint, request path : //oauth2/token
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-11 23:32:03,456] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  No resource class match for org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.revoke.OAuthRevocationEndpoint, request path : //oauth2/token
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-11 23:32:03,456] DEBUG {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils} -  No resource class match for org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.user.OpenIDConnectUserEndpoint, request path : //oauth2/token
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-11 23:32:03,456]  WARN {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor} -  No root resource matching request path //oauth2/token has been found, Relative Path: //oauth2/token. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-11 23:32:03,456]  WARN {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper} -  javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException
```

Comment: What is the EMM version You are using. Have you obtain the singed CSR for the version you are using ?

Comment: EMM version: wso2emm-2.0.0, yes, we have signed CSR from wso technical team.